# Flexbox: Align-self: center doesn't work with position: fixed in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I've a problem with aligning a div horizontally with flexbox in Firefox. It works fine in Chrome.

This is the code:

```
<header id="header">
    <p class="small-hidden">I am</p>
    <h1>Håkan</h1>
    <p>web designer from Sweden, living in the Basque Country, Spain</p>
    <div class="contact-icons">
        <a href="#.com"><i class="mi mi-Mail"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="mi mi-whatsapp"></i></a>
        <a href="#contact"><i class="mi mi-PenPalette"></i></a>
    </div>
</header>    
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------

header {
  background-image: url(../img/hakan_mobile.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:  flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  color: #777;
  }
@media only screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  header {
    background-image: url(../img/hakan.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 40vw;
    position: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }
  }
.contact-icons {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  }
@media only screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .contact-icons {
    bottom: 2rem;
    top: inherit;
    }
  }
```

What I want to do is place the text (p + h1 + p) in the lower part of the header, and the links should be centered and fixed in the top of the screen on small screens and centered at the bottom on larger screens. But if I use `position: fixed` (which is needed to keep the links visible at the top of the screen when scrolling down on a mobile) the `.contact-icons` will not center horizontally. It works if I remove `position: fixed` though.

I have tried both `align-items: center` on the container and `align-self: center` on `.contact-icons` but with the same result.

In Chrome with works perfect, but I can't make it work in Firefox. Any suggestions?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1qrqxd7m/

On the fiddle it looks almost centered, but still not. On my working copy it looks even more off center.

Comment: I would glady help, but can you set up a snippet somewhere? For example reformat the code to SCSS and put it in jsfiddle? Also what is `bp-large`? Can you clean that up a bit?

Comment: Sorry! Adopted to CSS and added Fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `position: fixed`, styles of the flex container aren't really expected to affect the .contact-icons positioning.

Just center them horizontally in relation to entire page with this:

```
position: fixed
left: 50%
transform: translateX(-50%)
```

Comment: My bad... The header is not full width on large screen(but 40vw) and using this will center the `.contact-icons` on the full screen. Also, on smaller size the icons in `.contact-icons` start at 50% and stack ontop of each other...

Comment: If it's 40vw, just set `left: 20vw` on .contact-icons. This snippet is universal and can be used in every case just like "set `left` to half of parent container and then `transform: translateX(-50%)`".

Comment: It's not working the way I would imagine... it's not centered, but the `.contact-icons` container start at 50%.

Comment: The thing is, if I use my orginal code, but remove `position: fixed` it lines up exactly like I want... But I lose the fixed position...

Comment: Can you please update the fiddle to illustrate the issue you're having? Otherwise I'm unable to guess what's wrong. I'm pretty sure the code I provided is correct and it seems enough to figure out how to use `left` property in your case.

Comment: The weird thing is that it works in the fiddle with your solution (thanks a lot) but it my project it still doesn't work... So somethign else somewhere must be interfering but I can't figure out what part...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try special for Firefox used "position: sticky;"

Comment: @Håkan your https://jsfiddle.net/1qrqxd7m/ It looks the same in chrome and firefox(

Comment: yes, I realized that now... but it the working project it's still not good. maybe some other thing is conflicting...